# C# backgroundworker & eventhandler together - searching USB devices

Tags: c#, mvvm, backgroundworker, eventhandler

I am first time using BackGroundWorker and EventHandler. I dont know if I am doing it correctly or not. I want to search for USB devices connected (just which have certain VID & PID). Because by debugging program dont want to go inside bw_worker_dowork loop.

I also using WPF with MVVM method - for info.

Please for help. I am doing it correctly or not?

```
    BackgroundWorker bw_worker;
    USBmiddleware cs = new USBmiddleware();


    public Windows1ViewModel()
    {
        bw_worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw_worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_worker_dowork);
        bw_worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bw_worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;


    }

    void bw_worker_dowork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        WqlEventQuery insertQuery = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 2 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_USBHub'");

        ManagementEventWatcher insertWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(insertQuery);
        insertWatcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(DeviceInsertedEvent);
        insertWatcher.Start();

        WqlEventQuery removeQuery = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM __InstanceDeletionEvent WITHIN 2 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_USBHub'");
        ManagementEventWatcher removeWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(removeQuery);
        removeWatcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(DeviceRemovedEvent);
        removeWatcher.Start();

        // Do something while waiting for events
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20000000);
    }

    void DeviceInsertedEvent(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
    {
        cs.FindDevices();
    }

    void DeviceRemovedEvent(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
    {
        cs.FindDevices();
    }
```

Comment: I just want that Windows open and search of USB devices is going on all the time in background :)

Comment: You shouldn't need the `BackgroundWorker` at all, as long as the `insertWatcher` and `removeWatcher` objects remain in scope.  Move the content of the `bw_worker_dowork` method (apart from the `Sleep`) into the constructor and it should work.

Comment: I test also version without BackgroundWorker, but then I have problem that nothing happend when I plug device in or unplug it

Answer (score 0):

You didn't start your BackgroundWorker !
[BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h01xszh2(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks! But now when I unplug the device and plug it back in, nothing happend :)

Comment: It is not EventWatcher a EventWatcher? :) when something happens then reaction is happend? Or I mistaking (because I am pretty fresh in C#)?

Comment: Or I am doing something wrong, because I defined EventWatcher in ViewModel of MVVM? Or how it is the right way?

Comment: Sorry, I don't known anything about EventWatcher or MVVM !.. :(

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. Problem was there:

Before:

```
"SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 2 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_USBHub'"
```

Now:

```
"SELECT * FROM Win32_DeviceChangeEvent WHERE       EventType = 2"
```

Before was working only on my USB Headset, now working also for my other device :) Sorry.